# Color sine parametric knot with R and ggplot2

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

This time I wanted to use R and ggplot2 in order to produce some simple mathematical knots, and color them according to tri-colorability.

This is my code

```
library (ggplot2)

theme_set(theme_bw())

phi = seq(2*pi, length = 1000)

x = sin(phi)+2*sin(2*phi)
y = cos(phi)-2*cos(2*phi)
z = -sin(3*phi)

diff <- abs(x - y)
mindiff <- sort(diff)[1:3] #knot-specific number of intersections
dindice <- which(diff %in% mindiff)
dcol <- c(rep(1,(length(0:dindice[1]))-1), rep(2,(length(dindice[1]:dindice[2]))-1), rep(3,(length(dindice[2]:dindice[3])-1)), rep(1,(length(dindice[3]:length(diff)))-1))

ggknot <- data.frame(x,y,z, dcol)
knot <- ggplot(ggknot, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(dcol)))
```

As you can see x and y are functions for generating the sine and cosine component of a knot, and phi is the vector of evenly spaced linear values. My idea was to find points in x,y plane that are nearest by calculating their difference and finding the first three minimal ones (dcol) to use for indexing and grouping for ggplot. But the result looks like this:
[image: ggplot2 of trifoil knot]
Colors are irregularly alternating and they should be like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricolorability). The inspiration for this was the awesome [glowing python blog](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2013-06-16T09:38:00%2b01:00&max-results=3&start=3&by-date=false), so a solution in python is also welcomed. Any ideas?

Comment: You have found the intersection points, but the function does not generate the points in any kind of 'order' (plot the first 40 to see what I mean), so you can't just cut up the data points by the intersections. Identifying which points are 'between' the intersections will be a lot more tricky.

Comment: I should say that the order that the function generates the points isn't obvious to me. There likely is an order which could be used to colour the knot sections.

Comment: Does `diff <- abs(x - y)` generate the intersections?  Seems like the minimum of that just finds the points nearest to the line `y = x`?

Comment: @JLLagrange Yes, you are correct, he did not find the intersection points, he just found the points nearest to the diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `phi = seq(2*pi, length = 1000)` generates 994 points from 2*pi to 1000.  Combining this with the previous observation on the intersections suggests that this is the right approach:

```
phi = seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 1200) - .27
x = sin(phi)+2*sin(2*phi)
y = cos(phi)-2*cos(2*phi)
z = -sin(3*phi)

dcol <- c(rep(1, 400), rep(2, 400), rep(3, 400))
ggknot <- data.frame(x,y,z, dcol)
knot <- ggplot(ggknot, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = as.factor(dcol)))
```

The "magic number" 0.27 was found algebraically for the (x, y) intersection of the equations.  `dcol` was chosen since the colors should be even spaced (by symmetry).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and this wonderful suggestion. I will look into it quickly and try to adjust. Only maybe there is an explicit solution without manual calculations? Final intention behind this is maybe a general purpose function for parametric trigonometric knots.

Comment: If you wanted to do this in general, it feels like the complexity would be O(n^2), since you'd want to compare all (x,y) doubles with all other (x,y) doubles.  On the plus side, n is the number of points you plot, so you could always start with, say 100 points, have a function to find the intersections, then plot again with 1000 points?  Also, note that your `z` variable is never used!

Comment: I was saving z for possible 3D rgl knot, but for now it`s just 2D, until I solve another thing. Namely, I`m unsure how you`ve found the "magic number" since maths is not on my stronger side. Thanks for the update on a function with "magic number".

Comment: To solve exactly, you need to simultaneously solve `sin(y)+2*sin(2*y) == sin(x)+2*sin(2*x) and cos(y)-2*cos(2*y) == cos(x)-2*cos(2*x)` for x and y.  This gives you all the angles where the curves intersect.  There should be 6 such solutions with x!=y (since the knot has three intersections, and by symmetry).  Honestly, I just [plotted in in wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28y%29%2B2*sin%282*y%29+%3D%3D+sin%28x%29%2B2*sin%282*x%29+and+cos%28y%29-2*cos%282*y%29+%3D%3D+cos%28x%29-2*cos%282*x%29%2C+x+%3D+0+to+2*pi%2C+y+%3D+0+to+2+*+pi) to get close!